# calculate shipping cost in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping

I want to set my shipping cost depending on the product  weight.
if **weight<=5kg**, shipping **cost=5AED**
if **weight>5kg**, then shipping cost will be increased by **2AED** for each **1kg**.

Answer (score 2):

[You can find here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/) a nice tutorial provided by Domagoj Potkoc from Inchoo.
It shows you the basics of how to create a shipping method in Magento 2.
It includes classes and configuration files.
But the example generates a flat rate shipping method.
You will need to modify the method `\Inchoo\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Example::collectRates()`.
Instead of the line `$amount = $this->getConfigData('price');` you should add this:

```
$weight = $request->getPackageWeight();
//default cost
$amount = 5;
//if the total weight is over 5 add 2 for each kg
if ($weight > 5) {
    $intWeight = ceil($weight)
    $amount += 2 * ($intWeight - 5);
}
```

The rest of the code should be as in the tutorial. Of course feel free to change the namespaces and class names.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marius, for the quick response. I will check it. I have one more question ,i don't know whether it is possible.Is there is any option from the admin side to satisfy my above need. bcoz i tried to import csv,it showed an error message. can you please tell how to write the csv file.please..thankz in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i faced a problem it shows "The file** /tmp/home/username/tmp/php2VLzjb** doesn't exist". 
i solved this issue by changing the php.ini file. then put a semi-colon(;) in front of upload_tmp_dir = /home/username/tmp. then restart xampp.